# hostname of the target in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have to copy files, which are target specific files. I have stored these files in my machine as their target hostnames.

Example:

/tmp/Server1.cfg
/tmp/Server2.cfg

```
host file has 

Server1
Server2
```

When my playbook runs for Server1 it should copy Server1.cfg. 
When my playbook runs for Server2 it should copy Server2.cfg.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks. 
PS: Please be explicit as I am still a toddler in ansible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to read some chapters at [docs.ansible.com](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts):

> Additionally, `inventory_hostname` is the name of the hostname as configured in Ansible’s inventory host file. This can be useful for when you don’t want to rely on the discovered hostname `ansible_hostname` or for other mysterious reasons.

So, in your case:

```
- copy:
    src: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}.cfg"
```